# Splitting task among several functions 

Tags: c++, coding-style

I am looking for something which enables me to do something like a function in a function.
Here is an example to make it more obvious:

```
class A{
 private: 
 int n;
 int c;
 public:
 void foo();
}
```

However foo is a function with is supposed to change c, but needs n for that. `foo` is somewhat complicated so I want to split it into different subfunctions.
Since `foo` needs `n` it is not simple doable through a friend function (without passing n (there are tons of variables in my real problem)

Comment: I do not see any "real" problem here. both n & c are inside the same class? And splitting a function should not be an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Just put all those sub-functions inside the same class and make them private?

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
    int n;
    int c;
    void foo_thing_1();
    void foo_thing_2();
public:
    void foo() { foo_thing_1(); foo_thing_2(); }
};
```

Comment: So there is no way around that? : )
Damn

Comment: @Bios: what is your actual problem? You didn't explain anything, and the general idea in this answer covers most sensible designs for complex classes.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed by other answers already, simple private functions should suffice - unless you also need acess to original function internal variables - which in c++11 is not possible. In upcoming c++0x you might want to look at lambda functions - though i am sure that's not what they were meant for.